# scons: objects, sources, executables, all in separate directories

Tags: c++, python, build, compilation, scons

I'm new to scons and I managed to figure out how to redirect the binaries (executables+objects) that one (con)script produces into another directory.

In my main project directory (root), I have a single `SConstruct` file, which contains the following line:

```
SConscript("source/SConscript", variant_dir="bin")
```

As evident, it sets the build (variant) directory of the `source/SConscript` script to be `bin`.

`source/SConscript`:

```
common = []

env = Environment()
env.Program("test", ["test.cpp"] + common)
env.Program("sdl-test", ["sdl_test.cpp"] + common, LIBS=["SDL2"])
```

My current setup is less than idea...

I'd like to have all the object files end up in `object`, keep all the source files in `source`, and have the final program binaries be built in `bin` directory.

How can I achieve that with scons? (Preferably without any messing with imperative (regular) Python, I hope that this is a built-in feature.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding another SConscript script for the objects where you would set the variant_dir to a different directory, it would look something like this:

**SConstruct**

```
env = Environment()
SConscript('source/SConscript_obj', variant_dir='object',
           duplicate=0, exports='env')
SConscript('source/SConscript', variant_dir='bin',
           duplicate=0, exports='env')
```

**source/SConscript_obj**

```
Import('env')

env.Object("test.cpp")
env.Object("sdl_test.cpp")
```

**source/SConscript**

```
Import('env')

env.Program("test", ["#/object/test.o"])
env.Program("sdl-test", ["#/object/sdl_test.o"], LIBS=["SDL2"])
```

Or, in SConscript_obj, you could make a library instead of just compiling objects.

You could also consider adding calls to VariantDir in the existing SConscript, but Im not sure how well that would work.

Comment: Why did you export/import the environment?

Comment: @yannbane Its just good practice. This way the entire build will use the same environment. If you do this and then need to make localized changes, you can clone it: cloned_env = env.Clone()

Comment: @yannbane Also notice the 'duplicate=0' parameter. That's not necessary either, but as I have it here, it wont copy the source code to the variant_dir.

Comment: OK, but what's the point of exporting/importing if the build is done on the same machine? Wouldn't each call to `Environment()` return the same object? Also, thanks for the duplicate tip.

Comment: @yannbane Each call to Environment() returns a different object, and if you set something on an env in the root SConstruct (like include pahts), then those values wont be visible in different SConscript's unless the env is exported/imported.

Comment: Also another question, what's the `#` in `"#/object/..." for exactly?

Comment: @yannbane In SCons the '#' character means that the path is relative to the root SConstruct script.